# Levi-Civita connection as an Ehresmann connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I've been trying to learn how to define the Levi-Civita connection as an Ehresmann connection, and I am getting quite confused. hoj201's answer on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34088/a-geometric-interpretation-of-the-levi-civita-connection suggests that we can define the Levi-Civita connection as a certain Ehresmann connection of $\pi : TM\to M,$ but I am a little confused and am unsure their construction works.

1. How does one define the Levi-Civita connection as an Ehresmann connection?
2. What is the horizontal lift of a curve along $\pi$? If $\gamma : [0,1]\to M$ is a curve, is its horizontal lift just $\gamma' : [0,1]\to TM$?

Comment: On (2): Note that if one has an Ehresmann connection on a bundle $E \to B$, in general a curve $\gamma: [0, 1] \to M$ will have many horizontal lifts -- specifically, there is a unique lift for _each_ point $q$ in the fiber $F$ over $\gamma(0)$. In the case of the tangent bundle, this means you get a lift for every vector $v \in T_{\gamma(0)}M$; this lift is, of course, (for the Ehresmann connection corresponding to the Levi-Civita connection) the parallel transport of $v$ along $\gamma$.

Comment: For $1)$ I would look at Foundations of Differential Geometry Vol 1. There is an explicit proof of the existence and uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connections in the language of connection one forms on principal bundles, which is equivalent to Ehresmann connections.